# Backpropogation "The hardest derivation I have seen in machine learning"?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, mathematics

In week 3 of Andrew Ng's "Neural Networks and Deep Learning" on Coursera there is a video titled "Backpropogation Intuition" during which he gives the full vectorized backpropogation formula, and ends the lecture suggesting that students who are good at calculus try to derive these from first principles, saying "it is one of the hardest derivations I have seen in the whole machine learning".

Please can someone post a link to a source that gives this derivation, ideally, using the same notation as Andrew Ng:

[image]

Comment: Andrew NG's always trys to simplifies the complicated backprop, I am not sure but it seems that it's for a NN so try working right from backwards if you want to derive this by drawing the diagram which shows all the operations, then backprop is very easy to derive... Also check the resources Section in that case...

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake.

Comment: See this for more visual explanation http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Backprop/